# ftp move files every night

Tags: bash, shell-script, backup

i have a FTP in a LAN that all day users upload content.
This gets bulky and messy due to the large amount of files.
Every day i create a new folder with the date and then move all the files from this day, so it can be categorised based on date.
i would like to automate it and make a script to run every night at 12:01

- create a folder with the previous date
- move all files from the particular day to tha folder

up to now i have found but i do not know how to create the folder based on date and then move all this files to that particular folder.
some help please?

Comment: What FTP server are you using, and what Unix?

Answer (score 0):

You can write a bash script and add it to daily crontab.

```
YOUR_DIR=/your/dir   #All of files in here
YOUR_DEST_DIR=/your/dest   #
YESTERDAY=`date +"%F" -d '1 days ago'`
mkdir -p $YOUR_DEST_DIR/$YESTERDAY 
mv $YOUR_DIR/* $YOUR_DEST_DIR/$YESTERDAY # move all files in your dir to dest folder with "based on previous date"
```

Add it to your crontab with every night ad 00:01

1 0 * * *

Comment: It is not clear from the question whether the user has access to GNU `date`, and it's not clear from your answer what the current directory is supposed to be (where `*` is expanded).

Comment: What would happen with files that are in the process of being transferred (especially if `$YOUR_DIR` is on another filesystem)?

Comment: the solution is for 2 different setups. One setup has a Debian 9 and the other Ubuntu 16. Both run proftp software. Both are getting correct date and time from ntp. The working directory is in /home/userA/ftp/ and the script will be run as root.